# Can I permanently reject a SendGrid Inbound Parse message so that re-delivery is not attempted?

Tags: sendgrid

Is it possible to permanently reject a given SendGrid Inbound Parse message so that delivery is not re-attempted?  Should I return "HTTP 406-Not Acceptable" to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is not possible with SendGrid Inbound Parse (although it is with MailGun).